# Is a US-to-International connection in Vancouver in 1 hour 13 mins possible?

Tags: seattle, taipei, yvr

This March I will be transferring in Vancouver, arriving on a flight from Seattle, and continuing to Asia. (This means I only have to clear the CBSA, where they check your passport and boarding passes). My layover is about 1 hour and 13 minutes.

Is it possible for me to still make it on time even with a small delay? Is there anyone who flew from SeaTac to YVR and transiting to an international flight and made it?

Both flights are on Air Canada, and it's a single-ticket trip.

I am asking this fairly early because I am a nervous wreck who hasn't taken transfer flights before. There's only one flight per day going out to the destination in Asia with Air Canada.

Comment: @SamJones the YVR site states that one doesn't need to pick up checked luggage and re-check it in this situation. There doesn't seem to be a requirement to go through security either. However one does indeed need to go through passport control. http://www.yvr.ca/en/passengers/navigate-yvr/passenger-guides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum Connection time for US to International in Vancouver is 60 Minutes according to https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/plan/check-in-information/minimum-connection-times.html , that means that you have a good chance of making it in and that Air Canada will take care of you, if you don't.

However, it's vulnerable to small delays and two long lines at Immigration & Customs. I had a similar connection once in Ottawa and the only way I made it was by begging my way through the Immigration line. I got lucky, since most other people didn't connect themselves and so they where happy to let me go ahead.

Comment: Is there not an expedited Customs clearance process for international connecting passengers at YVR?  I understood some airports (e.g. YYZ) have this, but I never make such connections, since I always originate trips from Canada.